# Installing tfjs in Mac M1pro

Tags: npm, tensorflow.js

I'm installing tfjs on my Mac, however, i've spent a lot of time struggling.

My Mac version is: Monterey 12.6, M1 silicon

My node version:18.8.0(in fact, i falied using other versions as well,16.18.0 e.g.)

npm version: 8.18.0

i've tried a lot of methods, including change the version of python, change the version of npm and node, none of them worked.

The error is as follows:

```
npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /Users/zhanghan/R_projects/site/helloworld/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c -- node scripts/install.js
npm ERR! CPU-darwin-4.1.0.tar.gz
npm ERR! https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/libtensorflow_r2_7_darwin_arm64_cpu.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp install failed with error: Error: Command failed: node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node-pre-gyp@1.0.9
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info using node@18.8.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp info check checked for "/Users/zhanghan/R_projects/site/helloworld/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8/tfjs_binding.node" (not found)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp http GET https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.1.0/CPU-darwin-4.1.0.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! install response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.1.0/CPU-darwin-4.1.0.tar.gz
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Pre-built binaries not installable for @tensorflow/tfjs-node@4.1.0 and node@18.8.0 (node-v108 ABI, unknown) (falling back to source compile with node-gyp)
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp WARN Hit error response status 404 Not Found on https://storage.googleapis.com/tf-builds/pre-built-binary/napi-v8/4.1.0/CPU-darwin-4.1.0.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.8.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.8.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info find Python using Python version 3.9.12 found at "/opt/anaconda3/envs/mujoco/bin/python3"
npm ERR! gyp WARN EACCES current user ("zhanghan") does not have permission to access the dev dir "/Users/zhanghan/Library/Caches/node-gyp/18.8.0"
npm ERR! gyp WARN EACCES attempting to reinstall using temporary dev dir "/var/folders/nd/sbq4px9x4bqd0yrtkrp2y3zh0000gn/T/.node-gyp"
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.8.0/node-v18.8.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.8.0/node-v18.8.0-headers.tar.gz
npm ERR! gyp http GET https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.8.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp http 200 https://nodejs.org/download/release/v18.8.0/SHASUMS256.txt
npm ERR! gyp info spawn /opt/anaconda3/envs/mujoco/bin/python3
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/zhanghan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/gyp/gyp_main.py',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'binding.gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-f',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'make',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/zhanghan/R_projects/site/helloworld/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/build/config.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/Users/zhanghan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/addon.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-I',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '/var/folders/nd/sbq4px9x4bqd0yrtkrp2y3zh0000gn/T/.node-gyp/18.8.0/include/node/common.gypi',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dlibrary=shared_library',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dvisibility=default',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_root_dir=/var/folders/nd/sbq4px9x4bqd0yrtkrp2y3zh0000gn/T/.node-gyp/18.8.0',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_gyp_dir=/Users/zhanghan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_lib_file=/var/folders/nd/sbq4px9x4bqd0yrtkrp2y3zh0000gn/T/.node-gyp/18.8.0/<(target_arch)/node.lib',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dmodule_root_dir=/Users/zhanghan/R_projects/site/helloworld/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Dnode_engine=v8',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--depth=.',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--no-parallel',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '--generator-output',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   'build',
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args   '-Goutput_dir=.'
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args ]
npm ERR! gyp info ok
npm ERR! gyp info it worked if it ends with ok
npm ERR! gyp info using node-gyp@9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp info using node@18.8.0 | darwin | arm64
npm ERR! gyp info spawn make
npm ERR! gyp info spawn args [ 'BUILDTYPE=Release', '-C', 'build' ]
npm ERR! make: /usr/local/opt/llvm/bin/clang++: No such file or directory
npm ERR! make: *** [Release/obj.target/tfjs_binding/binding/tfjs_backend.o] Error 1
npm ERR! gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/Users/zhanghan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:201:23)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (node:events:513:28)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess._handle.onexit (node:internal/child_process:291:12)
npm ERR! gyp ERR! System Darwin 21.6.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! command "/Users/zhanghan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.8.0/bin/node" "/Users/zhanghan/.nvm/versions/node/v18.8.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "build" "--fallback-to-build" "--module=/Users/zhanghan/R_projects/site/helloworld/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8/tfjs_binding.node" "--module_name=tfjs_binding" "--module_path=/Users/zhanghan/R_projects/site/helloworld/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node/lib/napi-v8" "--napi_version=8" "--node_abi_napi=napi" "--napi_build_version=8" "--node_napi_label=napi-v8"
npm ERR! gyp ERR! cwd /Users/zhanghan/R_projects/site/helloworld/node_modules/@tensorflow/tfjs-node
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node -v v18.8.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v9.1.0
npm ERR! gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! build error
npm ERR! node-pre-gyp ERR! stack Error: Failed to execute
```

Hope someone can help with me!

Comment: I had to add the TF metal plugin before I was able to install the tfjs-node dependency to projects on my Mac: https://developer.apple.com/metal/tensorflow-plugin/

Comment: Thanks! I failed to install tf metal with error though(failed at pip install tf-macos step), looks like Mac has poor compatibility with tf.